# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/maven/artifact/Artifact

Tags: android, robolectric, android-annotations

I have an Android project with Robolectric.

My application related classes are placed in `src/main/java` and test related classes in `src/test/java`.

I have these test dependencies in my `pom.xml`

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.robolectric</groupId>
            <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

When building and deploying from console with `mvn package android:deploy` everything is ok. 
Problem occurs when launching project from Eclipse (Juno).

```
[2013-03-24 12:27:26 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/maven/artifact/Artifact;
[2013-03-24 12:27:26 - my-app] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/maven/artifact/Artifact;
```

It appears that dependencies that are required for Robolectric only are included. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation it appears to be a m2e-android related [issue](https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/52)

Answer (score 5):

in the folder bin/dexedlibs you have a duplicate jar

1. remove it
2. make a clean of preject
3. retry

Comment: That is not the case. bin/dexedLibs contains ALL dependencies. Even these that are required for testing. Such as maven-project, maven-profile, wagon-file and so on. How do I keep them out of there?

Answer (score 1):

I once encountered same error. At the end, I found it is caused by including MoPubView's jar twice:

```
- On the one hand, I imported the MoPubView project via Eclipse Menu function "File | Import";  

 -> then right click my project, select "Properties"; 
 -> In the left bar, select "android";
 -> In the "Library" section at the right, press [Add] button...  

- On the other hand, I copied the mopub-sdk.jar to the /libs folder of my project.
```

I deleted the latter. It is solved.