# Android Dex:Unable to execute DX (IntelliJ), How to solve?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I try remove my bin directory clean and rebuild my project. I've gone through my project structure and made sure no library has been used multiple times.
I followed 
[Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/maven/artifact/Artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597371/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lorg-apache-maven-artifact-arti)
But this doesn't solve my problem.

just to inform i used this two library
[AndroidPDFViewerLibrary](https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library) , [droidText.0.2](https://code.google.com/p/kwi-walkthru/source/browse/trunk/kwmobile/libs/droidText.0.2.jar?spec=svn64&r=64)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's means you use 2 same classes in your project. Re-check your's dependency in project and make sure that you not use identical classes.

Duplicated class located in this line.

[image]

Comment: I imported this project into eclipse,its working fine, but intellij idea giving the same error...